# Looping through multiple columns in a database

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `PrevCourses` table where after a user takes a course, the course name is inputted in one of the columns along with the grade. For example:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Username     CourseName     Grade |
+-----------------------------------+
|   admin        CS100          A   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Now I have a `CurrentCourses` table as the following:

```
+-----------------------+
| Username   CourseName |
+-----------------------+
|  admin      BlahBlah  |
+-----------------------+
```

I also have a `Catalog` table:

```
+-----------------------+
|  CourseName    PreReq |
+-----------------------+
|   CS101        CS100  |
+-----------------------+
```

As you can see, `CS101` has a `prerequisite` of `CS100`. For me to be able to add `CS101` to the `CurrentCourses` table for the user `admin`, `CS100` must exist in the `PrevCourses` for the user `admin`. How can I check if `CS100` exists in the `PrevCourses` table and has a `grade < D` taken by the user `admin`.

Comment: _"push it into an array of type ResultSet"_ does not describe anything meaningful.  There's not enough information or context in your post to see a clear question.  Can you rephrase it and show us what you have already tried?  See the [help] for information on writing good questions.

Comment: can you share the database design, cause may be a single query can provide an answer to your question.